# Extracting a row from a 2-dimensional C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array called `resolvedStress` which can take `m x n` rows and columns. I would like to define a new variable called `criticalData` which is a 1D array containing just one row of `resolvedStress`. If I want to assign the 4th row to `criticalData`, would it be correct to write:

```
float* criticalData = &resolvedStress[4 * n];
```

I'm new to C++ so I'm not very confident yet!

Comment: It depends on how your array is organised. How is resolvedStress set up?

Comment: If you want to call a variable `stressData` you shouldn't use the name `criticalData`... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are itself a static pointer, no need to use '&', again as you said you wana point to 4th row so it would be 3 and not 4 as array index starts from 0.

```
float* criticalData = resolvedStress[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is organised as follows:

```
[ row0 | row1 | row2 | .... ]
```

That is, a 1D array containing the rows of the matrix in order, then `&resolvedStress[4 * n]` will be a pointer to `row4` - which is actually the 5th row of the array (gotta love zero indexing).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access fourth row of m X n array, you can access the each row as

```
  resolvedStress[0] will point to first row of the 2D array.
  resolvedStress[1] will point to second row of the 2D array.

  ...
  resolvedStress[m-1] will point to mth row of the 2D array.
```

for your case it would be

```
   float* criticalData = resolvedStress[3];
```